# auto login Linux 16.04

Tags: linux, autologin

i installed a minimal ISO of Ubuntu on my virtual machine .
after installing i installed these programs :

```
open-box
lightdm
```

everything's work fine
but when i want to do the auto login ,i get stuck .
i have read many forms and watched a lot of videos,consequently found ways but none of them works for me
the one that i'm eager to work with is lightdm.conf file :

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

in the file first thing i did was to delete the guess and it worked fine 
but the rest of the code dose not work at all

```
[SeatDefaults] 
allow-guest=false
autologin-user=saeed
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
```

since i am not using unity i did not write(but i did try the code before) this code:

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

saeed is my only user now , however i did try making another and auto login with it but the result was unsatisfying.

it's been around 12 hours of searching and trying ,it seems that everybody are getting the result but i keep getting the login screen 
since i am working on embedded device it is crucial to get rid of the login in the main device,
nevertheless i do need the password for SSH connections security .

your help is appreciated in advance

Comment: That's a well asked question you got there, but it's not for StakOverflow try posting it on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: thank you . i will post the question there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to leave out the "autologin-user-timeout=0".
I think there is a bug about that in Ubuntu 16.04.
I hope I could help you.

Comment: I could not get answer by lightdm , so i installed LXDM FULL !! just for its loggin manager and then i switched to openbox